# How to populate the live data from Server side to client side without using Timer

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is there any mechanisms [other than Update panel & Timer]are there which will populate the live data from server side to client side without using timer & without refreshing page. If it is there than please reply thank you.

Comment: Search on SignalR

Answer (score 1):

Please check out [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr), that's a great framework exactly for this purpose. Behind the scenes it uses web sockets, or it can fall back automatically to other techniques like long polling, if sockets are not supported. It's quite easy to set up a server and a client.

Of course you can go your own way and implement a solution based on polling or web sockets, but if you're already on the .NET platform server-side, I can very much suggest SignalR.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I have tried with SignalR & Other web socket also these works fine. I want know other than these any other mechanisms also there in order populate the live data in client side from server side.

Comment: There are no other magic techniques. The web was always a request-response based architecture. Your only *real* option is web sockets. Every other is just a simulation (polling the server for example), and not very efficient for heavy real-time scenarios.